# ef core - many to many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I been trying to use ef core recently, but there are something that is baffled in many-to-many relationship in ef core.

```
    public class Location
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<LocationInstructor> LocationInstructors { get; set; } = new List<LocationInstructor>();
}

public class Instructor
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<LocationInstructor> LocationInstructors { get; set; } = new List<LocationInstructor>();
}

public class LocationInstructor
{
    public Guid LocationId { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public Guid InstructorId { get; set; }
    public Instructor Instructor { get; set; }
}
```

and in dbcontext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<LocationInstructor>()
            .HasKey(bc => new { bc.LocationId, bc.InstructorId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<LocationInstructor>()
            .HasOne(bc => bc.Location)
            .WithMany(b => b.LocationInstructors)
            .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.InstructorId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<LocationInstructor>()
            .HasOne(bc => bc.Instructor)
            .WithMany(c => c.LocationInstructors)
            .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.LocationId);
    }
```

this is the operation that i try to perform

```
var instructors = new List<Instructor>
        {
            new Instructor(),new Instructor()
        };
        await applicationDbContext.Instructors.AddRangeAsync(instructors);


        Location location = new Location();

        foreach (var instructor in instructors)
        {
            location.LocationInstructors.Add(new LocationInstructor { Instructor= instructor, Location=location});
        }

        await applicationDbContext.Locations.AddAsync(location);
        await applicationDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

when i run this operation, i can see that below screenshots
[image]

so, my question is why does the 2 value differ? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've messed up the relationship mappings, basically associating `InstructorId` with `Location` and `LocationId` with `Instructor`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<LocationInstructor>()
    .HasOne(bc => bc.Location) // (1)
    .WithMany(b => b.LocationInstructors)
    .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.InstructorId); // (1)

modelBuilder.Entity<LocationInstructor>()
    .HasOne(bc => bc.Instructor) // (2)
    .WithMany(c => c.LocationInstructors)
    .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.LocationId); // (2)
```

Of course they should be paired (`LocationId`, `Location`) and (`InstructorId`, `Instructor`)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<LocationInstructor>()
    .HasOne(bc => bc.Location) // (1)
    .WithMany(b => b.LocationInstructors)
    .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.LocationId); // (1)

modelBuilder.Entity<LocationInstructor>()
    .HasOne(bc => bc.Instructor) // (2)
    .WithMany(c => c.LocationInstructors)
    .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.InstructorId); // (2)
```

which btw is the default conventional mapping, so these can be skipped (convention over configuration).

Answer (score 0):

Having a ICollection on both entities and registering the new entity/table via the Fluent API, will also work. With this approach you don't have to create the "middle object" yourself.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Location>()
        .HasMany(l => l.Instructors)
        .WithMany(i => i.Locations)
        .UsingEntity(t => t.ToTable("LocationInstructor"));
}
```